# Sum data based on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1 has several columns with distinct values.

```
Product,    
Type,   
Sales Amount,   
Value,  
Month,  
Year
```

What I want is this information combined and condensed to the different column levels, so that the `sale` and `value` amounts are sum’d based on the product and type in the year and months instead of each distinct line being displayed as a separate value.

For example if I have all columns being the same but the `sale` and `value` have distinct values I would want that to be sum’d together with the rows it corresponded to.
\

In addition, I want to know my loss ratio between the sale amount and the actual value of the product

```
Select Product,
Type,
Sale,
Value,
Month,
Year
Cast(value / sale as Dec) AS 'Loss Ratio' 

From Table 1
```

Some help please?

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results. Much easier to understand than a written description.

Comment: Am I confused or is this solveable by a group by and your loss ratio formula applied afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need a `GROUP BY` with `SUM`.

```
SELECT Product,
Type,
SUM(Sale) AS Sale,
SUM(Value) AS Value,
Month,
Year,
SUM(Sale)/SUM(Value) AS 'Loss Ratio' 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Month, Year, Product, Type
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4ef52/1)

Comment: this SEEMS to work but then i get this error

Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: Ah, then one of your value sums is 0. Not sure what you'd want to do in that case. Could just set the Loss Ratio to null by doing `SUM(Sale)/NULLIF(SUM(Value), 0)`